# Cypher matched results difer with "with" and without "with"

Tags: neo4j, cypher

First of all sorry for the clumsy title, I couldn't think of a better way to expose it.

The issue is I get different results when querying cypher in a single match---result  and when spliting it in a match --- with--- match ---result structure.

The match---result skips certain results.

My code:

match---result query

```
match (up:U)-[r1:COCS]->(op:O)-[r2:CCLS]->(jp:J)-[r3:PRE]->(n:J{id:"AC"})<-[j2o:CCLS]-(o:O)<-[o2u:COCS]-(u:U)
return up,type(r1), op, type(r2), jp, type(r3), n, type(j2o), o, type(o2u), u
```

Returns less results (there are results missing that match the path structure).

match--with---match---result query

```
match (up:U)-[r1:COCS]->(op:O)-[r2:CCLS]->(jp:J)-[r3:PRE]->(n:J{id:"AC"}) 
 with up, r1, op, r2, jp, r3, n 
match(n)<-[j2o:CCLS]-(o:O)<-[o2u:COCS]-(u:U)
return up,type(r1), op, type(r2), jp, type(r3), n, type(j2o), o, type(o2u), u
```

Returns the correct results

I do not understand why this is so. It makes no sense to me.

The way I understand how the with works,  both should return the same results. Can someone throw some light?

This is with Neo4J 2.1.6
Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I can think of an explanation for this seemingly anomalous behavior.

To quote from the [neo4j manual](http://neo4j.com/docs/2.2.1/cypherdoc-uniqueness.html):

> While pattern matching, Neo4j makes sure to not include matches where
>   the same graph relationship is found multiple times in a single
>   pattern. In most use cases, this is a sensible thing to do.

In your first query, the following sub-pattern appears twice (once on either side of the `(n)` node):

```
(:U)-[:COCS]->(:O)
```

Since the first query consists of a single pattern, Cypher would prevent the same `COCS` relationship from showing up twice in the same result row. In your case, this prevented some rows from showing up in the results.

Your second query splits the original query so that the above sub-pattern no longer appears twice in a single pattern. Therefore, you got "complete" results.

So, the lesson here is: **if you use a pattern that repeats a relationship subpattern, make sure that you really intend to filter out those rows in which the same relationship instance shows up multiple times.**